# Botão Voltar do navegador não funciona para votar para DIV

Tags: php, jquery, html5, css3

Tenho o código abaixo.

Quando estou no Início e clico no Menu para aparecer, por exemplo, Projetos e aperto em seguida no botão voltar do navegador, não dá certo. A url até muda, mas a página não volta para a div anterior, no caso Início.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function esconderDivs(){
        //Esconder Divs
        $('#projetos').hide();
        $('#lojaVirtual').hide();
        $('#quemSomosNos').hide();


        //Evento para deslizar o scroll e mostrar a div Início quando clica no Menu
        $('nav li:nth-child(1)').click(function(e){
            $('#projetos').hide();
            $('#lojaVirtual').hide();
            $('#quemSomosNos').hide();
            $('#meio').show();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#meio').offset().top}, 1000);

            })


        //Evento para deslizar o scroll e mostrar a div Projetos quando clica no Menu
        $('nav li:nth-child(2)').click(function(e){
            $('#meio').hide();
            $('#lojaVirtual').hide();
            $('#quemSomosNos').hide();
            $('#projetos').show();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#projetos').offset().top}, 1000);
            })


        //Evento para deslizar o scroll e mostrar a div Loja Virtual quando clica no Menu
        $('nav li:nth-child(3)').click(function(e){
            $('#meio').hide();
            $('#lojaVirtual').show();
            $('#quemSomosNos').hide();
            $('#projetos').hide();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#lojaVirtual').offset().top}, 1000);
            })

        //Evento para deslizar o scroll e mostrar a div Quem Somos Nós quando clica no Menu
        $('nav li:nth-child(5)').click(function(e){
            $('#meio').hide();
            $('#lojaVirtual').hide();
            $('#quemSomosNos').show();
            $('#projetos').hide();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#quemSomosNos').offset().top}, 1000);
            })
    }


    $(function(e){

        esconderDivs();

        $('#demo').carousel({
          interval: 7000
        });


        })

</script>
```

```
<?php include_once("_template/topo.php"); ?>        

<main>


    <!-- Sessão Início-->

    <section id="meio"> 

        <?php include("paginas/inicio.php") ?>


    </section> 


            <!-- Sessão Projetos-->
    <section id="projetos"> 

        <?php include("paginas/projetos.php") ?>

    </section>




    <!-- Sessão Loja Virtual-->

    <section id="lojaVirtual"> 

        <?php include("paginas/lojaVirtual.php") ?>


    </section>



    <section id="quemSomosNos"> 

            <?php include("paginas/quemSomosNos.php") ?>

    </section>


        <!-- Rodapé da página-->

        <?php include_once("_template/rodape.php"); ?>  


        <script src="src/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


</main>
```

Comment: Inverte a chamada dos scripts, pq o jQuery tem que ser o primeiro script a ser chamado na página, sempre. Você sabe para que serve o **(e)** que você declarou dentro de várias functions??

Comment: Inverti, mas nada mudou.